# git switch branch - how to get up to date with master?

Tags: git

I have two branches, `test` and `master`.

In `test`, I've deleted file.c, but in master I have not. I was working on the test branch and I wanted to switch back to master to make a quick change there.

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
```

This set my current branch to master, but did not restore file.c as I would have expected it to.

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

resets the repository as I'd like it to be, but does not seem like the correct solution.

If I switch branches, how do I get my local copy to match that of the branch that I've switched to? I would have expected `git pull` to do that, but maybe I'm misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely explanation for what happened is that when you were on branch `test`, after deleting `file.c`, **you didn't commit that change**. Once you commit the change, that commit will be on branch `test` and then when you switch to a different branch that still has the file, such as `master`, the file will come back.

Note that the misunderstanding can be seen in your wording of the question (which by the way is a very common misunderstanding):

> In `test`, I've deleted file.c, but in `master` I have not.

What you actually did, was delete `file.c` from your working folder while you had branch `test` checked out. But you have not committed that deletion to any branch yet.

The change is essentially following you around from branch to branch just waiting for you to do something with it. But it won't follow you everywhere. If you try to switch to a branch where `file.c` has been modified, this would be a conflict, so Git will stop and tell you to do something with your change before you proceed (such as stash, commit, or undo it).

**Side note:** the reset command that you used:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

essentially undoes all of your pending changes. If you had other changes you were working on, they would have also been undone, and potentially lost forever. If you want to just undo the pending change to a specific file, you could use:

```
git checkout file.c
# or the newer:
git restore file.c
```

Comment: This is the right answer. I'd just add that if you're looking to revert just the file you changed, you can `git checkout file.c` to get back to the committed version of `file.c`.

Comment: @Caleb good addition. I incorporated your comment. Side note, I just noticed that `restore` doesn't display "Updated 1 path from the index" like `checkout` does...